# can't modify the url parameters

Tags: php, mysql

what is wrong here guys?
i have written following code for updating url parameters "lat" and "lng" using mysql database columns degree_n , minute_n etc. but isnt happening. what I want is when everytime this script runs, the url should get modified using values present in MySQL database

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1116502_track_data";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
$url = "http://ws.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1116502_track_data";
$password = "***";
$dbname = "****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
$sql = "SELECT  degree_n, minute_n FROM coordinates  ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print " " .$row["degree_n"]. "." .$row["minute_n"]. " ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
 $conn->close();
?>&lng=<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1116502_track_data";
$password = "****";
$dbname = "****";

// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 } 
$sql = "SELECT degree_e, minute_e FROM coordinates  ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 ";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        print " " .$row["degree_e"]. "." .$row["minute_e"]. " ";
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
 $conn->close();
?>&username=****8";
echo "$url";

?>
```

Comment: what you have written in this line -> `$url = "http://ws.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat=<?php`  why php tag there and its not closing properly

Comment: Then you should modify the $url variable, don't you think so? You do not need to close the connection and then reconnect for evefy sql statement.

Comment: I did it without opening and closing <?php too...but its not working..it seems like I cant modify $url at all...nothing is working

Comment: First of all you have use " and ' wrong.. please correct it, in `$url` variable

Comment: Second what is purpose of assigning variable in url ?

Comment: correct it means how? ....nd I want to change lat and lng because I want to visit that geonames.com url everytime using different lat and lng values...so that it will show whch country the lat and lng belong to..

Comment: can you tell why you are passing connection credentials to geoname.com ?

Comment: I am not passing credentials to geoname .com, I just want to take data from MySQL database table of my site..thats why opening that connection...

Answer (score 0):

Use following code to obtain lat long from geonames.com

```
<?php
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "id1116502_track_data";
$password = "********";
$dbname = "id1116502_kk";

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
 }
// Create connection
$conn = new mysqli($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);

// Check connection
if ($conn->connect_error) {
    die("Connection failed: " . $conn->connect_error);
} 
//remove limit 1 is you want multiple data.  
$sql = "SELECT degree_e, minute_e FROM coordinates  ORDER BY id DESC limit 1 "; 
$result = $conn->query($sql);
$deg_e = "";
$min_e = "";
if ($result->num_rows > 0) {
    // output data of each row
    while($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
        $deg_e = $row["degree_e"];
        $min_e = $row["minute_e"];
        $url = file_get_contents('http://ws.geonames.org/countryCodeJSON?lat='.$deg_e.'&lng='.$min_e.'&username=demo');
        var_dump($url);
    }
} else {
    echo "0 results";
}
$conn->close();

?>
```

Comment: which credentials ? database credentials or api credentials ?